# Context menu edit - "Create new xxxxx"

Tags: windows-7, shell, context-menu

I am trying to find a way to create a context menu entry in which I can right-click on an .mp3 and have the option to create a folder based on the name of the file. I.e. Create New Folder "Artist".

Operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit.

Comment: In Ubuntu, Mac, Windows, Commodore 64?

Comment: @Blomkvist see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is through a simple script.

1. Copy and paste the following into notepad:

   ```
   @echo off
   md  c:\users\Spavek\mymusic\%~n1
   ```
2. Change `\users\Spavek\mymusic` to whatever directory you want to make your new folders in.
3. In the notepad save dialogue look towards the bottom and change file type to `all`, then save it as `CreateDirectory.Bat` in your Program Files directory.
4. Right click an Mp3 and select "open with". In the menu that pops up uncheck the box that asks if you always want to open with this. Select "Browse" and it should open up the Program file directory. Select the file you just made in notepad. Now every time you right click on an mp3 file, you will have `createdirectory` as an option.

And that's it. Let me know if you have any issues getting this to work.